# webkit gradient produces syntax error in lesscss

Tags: css, less

This is my first time experimenting with lesscss and am facing a problem with the following css/less code

```
body {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 0, 100, 50% 0, 0,
            from( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) ), to( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) ));
}
```

This is working fine as simple css, but the less compiler throws a syntax error at line 2. It doesn't give any other details. Can't I use webkit gradients when using less css? Or am I really doing wrong syntax?

Any help on this greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out less doesn't like when there are spaces in the `from` and `to` directives. Like

```
from( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) )
```

won't work. But

```
from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))
```

does. I personally feel this is a bug, but someone else might know better.

Answer (score 1):

A quick tutorial, Take a [look](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/10283)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me identify the problem (though indirectly). :)